# Use the same browser session for multiple tests with Selenium Pytest

Tags: python, selenium

I want to be able to use the same browser session for multiple tests within the same test file.

I have a class set up for the login:

```
class Loginpage ():
 url="http://appsv01:8084/#/"

 def __init__(self, workbook):
    self.workbook=workbook

 def login(self,value_Name,worksheet):
    #Open a new mymobile suite window in Chrome and maximize
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/temp/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("http://appsv01:8084")
    driver.maximize_window()
```

I've been closing the browser session and then opening a new one per test, but I tried changing it so that the structure looks like (in the file called test_mytests.py):

```
   #open the browser and log in
   mylogin=Loginpage('C:\Automation\Common_Objects.xlsx')
   driver=mylogin.login("AutoSMS", "Users")

   #perform the first test
   def test_one():
    task1
    task2

   #perform the second test
    def test_two():
    task3
    task4
```

This fails with the error:

```
E   ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

If I put the code for #open the browser under each test individually, then everything works fine. Is it possible to only open the browser once and have all the tests in the file work on that same browser session?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the driver object to the function calls:

```
 #open the browser
 driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/temp/chromedriver.exe')
 driver.get("http://appsv01:8084")
 driver.maximize_window()

 #perform the first test
 def test_one(driver):
  #do something with driver here, e.g.
  driver.find_element_by_id('test').click()


 #perform the second test
 def test_two(driver):
   task3
   task4

 #function calls
 test_one(driver)
 test_two(driver)

 #close driver
 driver.close()
```

Comment: I'm already using the driver (sorry, I should have included that in my original post):

class Loginpage ():
    url="http://appsv01:8084/#/"

    def __init__(self, workbook):
        self.workbook=workbook

    def login(self,value_Name,worksheet):
        #Open a new window in Chrome and maximize
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/temp/chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get("http://appsv01:8084")
        driver.maximize_window()

def test_one:
  mylogin = Loginpage('C:\Automation\Common_Objects.xlsx')
  driver = mylogin.login("AutoSMS", "Users")